# new user password disappear after I create in SQLdeveloper

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-11g, oracle-database

I have problem when I create new user so the password disappear after I create in SQL developer and when I tried to make connection its giving errors
please help.

Comment: in SQL developer I want to make a new user , I make it and I set the password but when I make connection using the same user I made its giving error that username or password are invalid , I saw that the password is erasing by it self after saving the user , may be that's why I can't make a connection.

Comment: Edit the question to make it more complete including the error you get and the more details you can. This will help in understanding the situation and finding an answer